# Why does my Pig Accumulator UDF not run in accumulator mode?

Tags: java, apache-pig, udf

I wrote an Accumulator UDF using Java. When I run the UDF on unsorted data, Pig (0.13.0) calls the `accumulate` method as desired:

```
output = FOREACH (GROUP input BY f) {
    GENERATE MyUDF(input);
}
```

I can tell that it's working because the log declares that the reducer is running in accumulative mode.

However, when I apply a secondary sort, Pig calls the `exec` method.

```
output = FOREACH (GROUP input BY f) {
    sorted = ORDER input BY f2;
    GENERATE MyUDF(sorted);
}
```

My worry here is that the `exec` method takes the entire bag into memory at the same time. My input is too large for this to work. That's why I implemented the `Accumulator` interface.

Does anyone know why the second example doesn't properly use the `accumulate` method? Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: This may be obvious, but have you tried running [explain](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/test.html#explain) or [illustrate](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/test.html#illustrate)?

Comment: I downvoted because the question of 'why' is quite broad, and you only state that you worry about something being a problem, without actually giving test results etc. If you run into a problem, one could help you to solve it, but as is I do not think this is a good question.